# send mail from my android application

Tags: java, android, android-listview, sendmail

I have to develop one android application.
here  i have to send mail from my android application.

I have to send mail listview vlaues from my android application.

This is my android code:

```
public class InvoiceOrder extends Activity {


String mGrandTotal,mTitle,total,mCost;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.invoice);
    ListView mLstView1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);


    CustomerAdapter mViewCartAdpt = new CustomerAdapter(
            InvoiceOrder.this);
    mLstView1.setAdapter(mViewCartAdpt);

            Button login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mBtnSubmit);
            login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            i.setType("message/rfc822");
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , new String[]{"demo@mercuryminds.com"});
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Testing");
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT   , "mLstView1");
            try {
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send mail..."));
            } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                Toast.makeText(InvoiceOrder.this, "There are no email clients installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
         }
      });
        }
```

The listview is displayed on these activity.how can i send that listview values to email.please give me solutions.

**EDIT:**

Hi I have **send mail automatically**.so i have used javamailapi.

Now i have changed my code like:

```
public class InvoiceOrder extends Activity {


String mGrandTotal,mTitle,total,mCost;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.invoice);
    ListView mLstView1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);


    CustomerAdapter mViewCartAdpt = new CustomerAdapter(
            InvoiceOrder.this);
    mLstView1.setAdapter(mViewCartAdpt);

            Button login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mBtnSubmit);
            login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
             Properties props = new Properties();
                props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
                props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
                props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",
                        "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
                props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
                props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");

                Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,
                    new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                            return new PasswordAuthentication("mroslinmhary@gmail.com","fg565jhjjh");
                        }
                    });

                try {

                    Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
                    message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("krishnaveni.veeman@mercuryminds.com"));
                    message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                            InternetAddress.parse("demo@mercuryminds.com"));
                    message.setSubject("Testing Subject");
                    message.setContent("This is your product name : "+
                            "Hi Krishna" +"<br></br>This is your price : "+ "Hi veni", "text/html; charset=utf-8");
                    Transport.send(message);

                    System.out.println("Done");

                } catch (MessagingException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
               }



      });
```

Now i have to send listview automaically to email .how can i set the content here.please give me idea.

Comment: Do you want to show the user a compose window or do you want to automatically send email from an account that you own?

Comment: @SLaks automatically send email from my account.

Comment: You can either give everyone your email password or set up a web service.

Comment: You should change your Gmail password.

Answer (score 2):

You need to have a web application that can receive a web command (REST possibly) that will take requests from your app and send out the email.

For instance, if your server is at example.com, then you can have a service that sends mail at a URL like the following:

example.com/sendmail/ and your POST variables would contain the following variables:
subject, fromAddress, toAddress, content, etc.

If you can program in a web based language like PHP, Ruby, Python or even Java then you can write this, and then just send the request from your app.

Comment: please see my edited question and give me solution for these.

Answer (score 0):

use below code to send the email

```
    Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        emailIntent.setType("plain/text");  
       emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , new String[]{"demo@mercuryminds.com"});
       emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject");
       emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "body text"); 
       startActivity(emailIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the data which you want to send as email in the ' message.setContent(' function. This would be added to the email body. (Iterate over the list view and get the data into a string variable before being added to the email message) Is that what you want?.

Comment: here the listview value is displayed like below image:https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B8m46AKj3sKwNi1GSHQwcTNQalk/edit    how can send that listview value to my email.

Answer (score 0):

For sending Email to user from android there are two ways a user can do it.
Method 1:
To use Intent. Code is as follow:

```
send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.emailsendbutton);

address = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emailaddress);

subject = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emailsubject);

emailtext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emailtext);

send.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

public void onClick(View v) {

// TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {
final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);

emailIntent.setType("image/png");

emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] { address.getText().toString() });

emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject.getText());
//emailIntent.setType("plain/text");
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, emailtext.getText());

emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("android.resource://"+ getPackageName() + "/" + R.drawable.ic_launcher));

Sendingmail2.this.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent,"Send mail..."));
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("", "sendPlainTextEmail() failed to start activity.", e);
        //Toast.makeText(this, "No handler", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"No handler", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
});
```

Method 2: 
Sending Email directly to some email id by entering static gmail id and password
Follow the following URL:
http://davanum.wordpress.com/2007/12/22/android-send-email-via-gmail-actually-via-smtp/

or one can ask for code by giving your email id here and will send you my code which I had done for sending email directly.